# Spring Boot One to One Relation Null Error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a user and a basket. A user can only have 1 basket.
I want to set the basket to the current user to whom I sent a request.

**I have a Basket Entity.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BASKETS")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Basket {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "basket")
    private User user;
}
```

**I have a User Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_basket_id")
    private Basket basket;

    public User(String name, String surname ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

**I have a method:**

```
 public Basket createBasket(User user, Long basketId) {
        Basket basket = findBasketById(basketId);
        if (basket == null) {
            basket = new Basket();
            basket.setId(basketId);
            basket.setUser(user);
            user.setBasket(basket);
        } else {
            basket.setUser(user);
            user.setBasket(basket);
        }
        return basketRepository.save(basket);
    }

protected Basket findBasketById(Long id) {
        return basketRepository.findById(id)
                .orElse(null);

    }
```

I am sending a request like this to see the information of the baskets.

- localhost:8080/v1/basket/getAll

I am getting such a response:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user": null
}
```

Although basket.setUser(user) is present, the user of the basket is null.

When I run the code in debug mode, the user of the basket appears, but the response is null.

I think there is a mistake in the design but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Did you checked if the user in the call `createBasket` is valid (not null)?

Comment: Yes, I checked, the user that comes as a parameter to the createBasket method is not null

Comment: Before return try setting user.setBasket(basket);

Comment: I'm already doing that, first I do user.setBasket(basket) and then I save by returning.

Comment: I fixed it as he said but I still get the error.

I updated the places where I fixed the code in the question. I left the error I got as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `@Data` annotation of the lombok library.

It cannot do Get and Set operations.

It was necessary to add `@Getter` and `@Setter` separately as annotations instead of `@Data` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to define a bi-directional one-to-one relationship based on your question:

in User entity:

```
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_basket_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Basket basket;
```

in Basket entity:

```
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "basket")
    @JsonBackReference
    @ToString.Exclude
    private User user;
```

*User* in this case is the owning side of the relationship. Only this table will have a foreign key column. *Basket* is a non-owning side. This table will not have (don't need) a foreign key. The rest is managed by JPA.

Please also mind the Json and ToString annotations. They are needed to avoid a circular reference causing an infinit loop and stack overflow.

To add a new basket to the a user you must set both sides. Preferably in a method like this:

in User entity:

```
    public addBasket(Basket basket) {
        setBasket(basket);
        basket.setUser(this);
    }
```

Comment: I fixed it as you said but I'm getting this error

A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.marketapp.MarketApp.model.Basket#1]

Comment: findBasketById(basketId) method is classically like this:
protected Basket findBasketById(Long id) {
        return basketRepository.findById(id)
                .orElse(null);

    }